# Symfony Error rendering in template

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have developed a custom login form without using CMD prompt and it does not have any relation with database.

I just want to validate it.I have applied the validators on username as `'name'    => new sfValidatorEmail(),`.The isValid function in the action working fine but how can i display the errors in Template file.

My Template code look like ,

`<?php echo $form ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo $form->renderGlobalErrors();` will output any global errors (such as security token errors), but not ones specific to a field (EG "this field is required" or "this field needs to be a 7 digit number"). I believe field specific errors are output when you render the whole form, but you can use `echo $form['field']->renderError()` to output the error for a specific field.

Comment: +1 for "I believe field specific errors are output when you render the whole form".

Answer (score 1):

You should read trough the chapter [Forms for web Designers](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers) on the symfony website.

Answer (score 0):

To display all errors you could use...

```
echo $form->renderGlobalErrors();
```